# magento theme product display box broken

Tags: html, css, magento, grid

I am running an online cosmetics store (http://www.beautyblust.com), just now I noticed the theme homepage product box height is way too much then it was. It was all fine 10 minutes ago, now the css box is broken and over height.

I would really appreciate if anyone can point me out the problem here and suggest how to resolve it.

Plz check the attached image for a clear view of the issue.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qYo4.jpg

Comment: Try disabling your javascript files and reenabling them one by one,  I guess this is a javascript problem because the width and height are declared as a property in your html.

Comment: there is some div is hidden. Try to inspect

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have removed the bestseller block from the homepage and seems like it was causing the problem. But I need this block back on.